# java.lang.NullPointerException Error

Tags: java

I am a beginner with Java .. & I keep getting this error .. java.lang.NullPointerException pointing to this line --> Double hOption = healthBenDesig.get("employeeOnly"); 
Can someone tell me if i am missing something or what exactly I am doing wrong please?

```
private HashMap<String, Double> healthBenDesig;

public VariableList()
    {
      HashMap<String, Double> healthBenDesig = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    }
public VariableList()
    {
      HashMap<String, Double> healthBenDesig = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    }
public void getHMP() 
    {
        Double hOption = healthBenDesig.get("employeeOnly");
        System.out.println("The health Option you chose is: " + hOption);

    }
    public HashMap setHealthOpt()
    {
        healthBenDesig.put("none", 0.00);
        healthBenDesig.put("employeeOnly", 311.87);
        healthBenDesig.put("spouse", 592.56);
        healthBenDesig.put("children", 717.30);
        healthBenDesig.put("kids", 882.60);

        System.out.println(healthBenDesig);
        return healthBenDesig;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're shadowing the healthBenDesig by re-declaring it in your constructors leaving the class field null. Don't re-declare it.

Change

```
public VariableList() {
    HashMap<String, Double> healthBenDesig = new HashMap<String, Double>();
}
```

to:

```
public VariableList() {
    healthBenDesig = new HashMap<String, Double>();
}
```

Comment: The "thank you" button is that tick mark that you see to the left of the answer.  It tells everyone that you've received a satisfactory answer to your question, and that no further answers are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are not intializing your class member healthBenDesig instead you are shadowing it using the lcoal variable. This is causing healthBenDesig as un-initialized and leading to `NullPointerException`. your In your constructor, change it from

```
    public VariableList()
    {
      // re-declaration or shadowing of memeber variable healthBenDesig
      HashMap<String, Double> healthBenDesig = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    }
```

to

```
    public VariableList()
    {
        healthBenDesig = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to initialize healthBenDesig at property declare

```
private HashMap<String, Double> healthBenDesig = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```